# Does anyone know of a polymorphic Haskell function that can do `fn2 (_1, _2._2) (3, (4, 5)) == (3, 5)` or similar?

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know of a polymorphic function that can do the following?

```
fn :: (a -> b, a -> c)         -> a -> (b, c)
fn :: (a -> b, a -> c, a -> d) -> a -> (b, c, d)
-- etc, supporting arbitrary length tuples.
```

I know I can do

```
((,,) <$> foo <*> bar <*> qux) baz
(liftA3 (,,) foo bar qux) baz
```

And I am wondering if I could somehow also do

```
fn (foo, bar) baz
fn (foo, bar, qux) baz
```

It's okay if the answer relies on the `lens` package.

And if it does, maybe it can be taken one step further allowing the following as well:

```
fn2 (_1, _2._2) (3, (4, 5)) == (3, 5)
```

Comment: Why is the last thing "one step further"? It looks to me like a solution to the previous bits would *already* be a solution to the last thing; it is "one fewer steps".

Comment: @DanielWagner I'd think there is an isomorphism between them such that `fn (foo, bar) baz` can be rewritten to become `fn2 (to foo, to bar) baz`, and `fn2 (_1, _2._2) qux` can be rewritten to become `fn2 (view _1, view $ _2._2) qux`. I thought that maybe the version that operates on regular functions may be easier and simpler to implement than the version that operates with lens getters. Hence I considered the lens version 'one step further'. I'm interested in either variant.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not really possible.

The closest you can get is to write a typeclass and give it one instance for each size of tuple up to 63-tuples; this is practically speaking "arbitrary length tuples" since GHC doesn't support longer ones. Indeed, in practice, most libraries that do similar things define instances up to 7-tuples or so and call it "practically arbitrary length tuples" since it is so rare to use tuples longer than that anyway.

Comment: Perhaps it could be doable with a drop of Template Haskell, or some kind of Typeable magic?

Comment: @DanielWagner I think I would be okay with that. I'm aware that many (most? all?) packages implement n-tuple support via typeclasses. I was just wondering if what I am asking might already exist somewhere implemented. And if not I might try to take a shot at it. I also was wondering if `Generics` could help in any way by allowing the tuples to be treated as a generic product type, although to this day I have very limited experience in that direction.

Comment: @Wizek, generics can almost certainly do the trick for fairly short tuples, but I think you'll run out of `Generic` instances at around 7-tuples. So you'll likely end up writing at least as much code to make generics work as you would to just write all the instances by hand. It's rather unfortunate, to be sure. As @IgnatInsarov suggests, Template Haskell can surely write all 63 instances, but I don't know TH myself yet.